# Checksum of versions does not match on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, bundle-install

Okay so I created a project on my old laptop in rails and heroku. I wish to access the files and push new edits to heroku on my laptop. They are all saved on Git so I am able to clone the git depository onto my new laptop.

My laptop had no previous software on it so I installed ruby and rails and the versions were fine but when I try and bundle install when the folder is open in command prompt I get the error "The checkum of /versions does not match the checksum provided by server! Something is wrong".

I am new to rails etc etc so I do not have a clue whats going on here I just want to setup my environment exactly the same as last time so I can start where I left off on my old laptop. I've tried numerous things like clearing the gems, updating the gems, reinstalling ruby and rails.

In addition to this when I try rails -v i get the error message "You do not have [insert gem name] try running bundle install" So i'll install the new gem and then i get the same error.

This has become a nightmare and I just want to find a clean way to install ruby and rails so that these errors will get out the way.

I created this project by following a guide so I guess I could do that all again but I would much prefer to just fix this current issue. I found one other occurrence of this happening to someone but it was in the case of creating a new file.

This is my gem file in the project

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.8'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.2'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this. I was having a similar problem. Same error.

Try running

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

If it doesn't let you, add `--force` at the end of the command.

Then reinstall bundler

```
gem install bundler
bundle
```

I also did some extra deleting, but I'm not sure that was necessary.

Comment: This worked for me too. In addition, I choose uninstall "All bundler versions" and yes to all.

Comment: @Cruz Nunez I'm still getting the error message,  what additional deleting did you do?

Answer (score 1):

had a similar Issue:

fixed using

> rm -rf ~/.bundle/cache